# Why do I see redefinition error in C?

Tags: c, visual-studio

Following is my code, I am trying to run it in Visual Studio.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
int main()
{
    //int i;
    //char j = 'g',k= 'c';
    struct book 
    {
        char name[10];
        char author[10];
        int callno;
    };
    struct book b1 = {"Basic", "there", 550};
    display ("Basic", "Basic", 550);
    printf("Press any key to coninute..");
    getch();
    return 0;
}

void display(char *s, char *t, int n)
{
    printf("%s %s %d \n", s, t, n);
}
```

It gives an error of redefinition on the line where opening brace of function is typed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You call `display` before declaring it, and in such cases the compiler assumes the return type is `int`, but your return type is `void`.

Declare the function before using it:

```
void display(char *s, char *t, int n);
int main() {
    // ...
```

Also note, that you declare it as receiving `char*`, but pass string literals to it (`const char*`) either change the declaration, or change the arguments, e.g:

```
void display(const char *s, const char *t, int n);
int main()
{
    // snip
    display ("Basic", "Basic", 550);
    //snap
}

void display(const char *s, const char *t, int n)
{
    printf("%s %s %d \n", s, t, n);
}
```

Comment: Nitty pick: In C, the elements of character string literals have type `char`, not `const char` as in C++.

Comment: @DanielFischer - could you elaborate? do you mean `char * a = "abc"` is better than `const char * a = "abc"` in C?

Comment: I mean that in C, `"Basic"` has type `char[6]`, not `const char[6]`. Since attempting to modify string literals is UB, it is better to assign them to `const char*`, but it's not the type they have by the language spec.